# Trouble while implementing UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uiscrollview

I am trying to add zooming capabilities on my imageView but some of the things are not working as it should work.

I followed  [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122139/uiscrollview-tutorial)
to add zooming capabilities on my imageView and make it center on the scrollView but I don't know why my imageView is not at center.

Please see this image [image].

Here  I have added the ScrollView (with constraints ) and inside of that, imageView with constraints as described in the tutorial but when am running it image is not at center see the second image:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

select the image view and change it on the right side to aspect fit[image: like this]